# python for loop not iterating over all indeces of list of dicts

Tags: python, iterator

I'm trying to iterate over a list of dicts to find a matching string.
This works on the first index but it doesn't work on the second index.

```
types = [{'type': '1'},
         {'type': '2'}]
#type = '1'
type = '2'

print(f'all types {types}')
print(f'length {len(types)}')
print(f'Getting type: {type}')

for tp in types:
    print(f'current index {tp}')
    if tp['type'] == type:
        print(f'found {type}')
        foundType = tp
    print(f'last match is {foundType}')
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Try to avoid `type` as variable name, because it is built-in function in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your first iteration your if statement is not True, so when you print at the end `foundtype` is not initiated so it doesn't know what to print

Comment: Ah thanks it was just an indentation fault on my side

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @makr3la, the following implements a better naming convention and fixes the explanation provided by @matman9

```
types = [{'type': '1'},
         {'type': '2'}]
find_this = '2'
for this_dict in types:
    if this_dict['type'] == find_this:
        print('found '+find_this)
```